# How to add a popup on onTap of a TextFormField

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I need to show a popup on tapping the textFormField, just like a dropDownButton, but I need to use controllers of textFormField so I cannot manage it with dropDown.

I was trying like this

```
                        Container(
                          width: 50,
                          child: TextFormField(
                            controller: _edits1,
                            autofocus: true,
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            maxLength: 3,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(counterText: ""),
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Comfortaa',
                                color: Colors.blueGrey,
                                fontSize: 30),
                            onEditingComplete: () => node.nextFocus(),
                            onTap: () {
                              PopupMenuItem(child: Text('One'));
                              PopupMenuItem(child: Text('Two'));
                            },

                          ),
                        ),
```

Or something similar.
How can I do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your TextFormField inside the IgnorePointer widget

```
Container(
  child: IgnorePointer(
    child: TextFormField(),
  ),
),
```

You can also use the InkWell widget to perform onTap on TextFormField

```
InkWell(
 onTap:(){},
  Container(
    child: IgnorePointer(
      child: TextFormField()
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. Why should I use IgnorePointer

Comment: IgnorePointer is to not focus the text field and show the keyboard when we click on it. Instead, you can have onTap with the help of InkWell on that TextFormField. You can set any value to _edits1(your controller) as _edits1.text = "Your_Value".

Comment: The problem is that no popup menù appears when I click on TextField